# Ограничение на перемещение мыши

Tags: javascript

Задача в том, что я не могу сделать так, чтобы мышь не доходила до блока. Нужно сделать так, чтобы, например, при расстоянии 10px мыши от блока блок переместился.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "myDiv";
with(div.style) {
  width = '100px';
  height = '100px';
  backgroundColor = 'red';
}
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
div.addEventListener('mouseover', count);


function draw() {
  this.style.left = Math.random() * document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
  this.style.top = Math.random() * document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
  mouseMove(event)
}

var x = 0;

function count() {
  this.innerHTML = x += 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: где объявлена функция _mouseMove_?

Comment: Если его убрать то блок не убежит

Comment: Небольшой блок снаружи мог бы караулить мышь на подходе..

Comment: нет задача именно в этом что его нельзя применять и есть способ с помощью padding но их использовать нельзя

Comment: Пусть тогда документ сам следит за мышами - и как только они подберутся поближе - убирает всё ценное куда подальше.

Comment: ну вот как это организовать не знаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пусть тогда документ сам следит за мышами - и как только они подберутся поближе - убирает всё ценное куда подальше.

```js
var cheese = document.querySelector('.cheese');

// За мышью следит сам документ:
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mm);
document.addEventListener('mouseover', mo);
var border = 10;

function mm(e) {
  if (e.clientX > cheese.offsetLeft - border &&
      e.clientX < cheese.offsetLeft + cheese.offsetWidth + border &&
      e.clientY > cheese.offsetTop - border &&
      e.clientY < cheese.offsetTop + cheese.offsetHeight + border
  ) { // если мышь слишком близко - убираем сыр!
  cheese.style.left = Math.random()* 
    (window.innerWidth - 30) + 'px';
  cheese.style.top = Math.random() *
    (window.innerHeight - 30) + 'px';
  }
}
function mo(e){
  if (e.target === cheese)
    cheese.innerText = +(cheese.innerText || 0)+1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.cheese {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cheese"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо все ок Большое тебе спасибо

Comment: Только дин вопрос document.querySelector почему вот это нельзя заменить на document.getElementById

Comment: Почему нельзя, разумеется можно. У вас вообще динамически элемент создавался - его и искать не нужно было. Это просто один из способов найти элемент - по имени класса.

Comment: Спасибо вы меня выручили

Comment: Вместо спасибо здесь принято нажимать зелёную галочку, чтобы принять ответ.